# convention for storing less source files in an mvc solution?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, less

The is just more of a conceptual question, but I wanted to ask here to see what others are doing and perhaps agree upon a convention. I maintain a nuget package that installs several css and javascript files. And because the css is compiled from less source files, I've recently been asked to include the less files in the package for those that wish to customize and compile it themselves. Right now i'm thinking Content/less. Any other suggestions?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, that's funny I was just debating over this the other day.

I ended up settling on pretty much the same thing you suggested `Content/Less`. But if I have a lot of stuff in the content folder I tend to do `Content/Styles/` in which case I would probably put the Less folder in there.

I like the idea of including the Less files in the package though, I could see that being useful.

Upvote for less.js though! So handy!

Comment: I ended up going with Content/Less in my package. I also included less.js in the Scripts folder :)